# How generate my reactiveform output angular

Tags: json, angular, api

I do not know how to manipulate a formanray

I have with the select input:

[example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtnsjc)

#### I want the output json like this:

**json**

```
{
  "comentario": "kkkkkkkkkkkk",
  "respuestas": [ { "idusuario": "",  "numero": "","iduser":"" } ] 
}
```

I get `iduser` from localstorage with that I have no problem

### I found the how to do it

Update I make this little  example but there a bug with select
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kj2ahg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Your form module (what you get from `Formulario.value`) does *not* need to match your data model.

Consider modeling your data as you need it coming from or getting saved to your data store. So in your example, *with* your `iduser`.

Then just map the data from your form data structure (`Formulario.value`) to your data structure.

Make sense?

For example, my data structure I want to send to my server could look like this:

```
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode: string;
  iduser: number;
}
```

I can copy the data from the form to this data structure like this:

```
const product = { ...this.myForm.value };
```

Then product contains all of the form fields. But, like in your example, the `iduser` is not on the form. So I can then use:

```
product.iduser = myUsersId;
```

To set the id. I then have a data structure I can pass to my backend.

Comment: sorry I failed to specify that my problem is in the select input  but I learn a lot  I made an independent example to what I'm doing have a bug I do not want generate the same output the original i want add numbero https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kj2ahg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html